# Does Spring Data 2.0 change nullability rules about sorting and paging?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm making migration from spring-boot 1.5.6 to 2.1.7 and facing so many issues.

When I see discussion about migration, looks simple but not for me. I got 2 very big issues :

1. I implement a filter to make a process of uncrypt uri and to call filter once again with request dispatcher. In 1.5.6 the code is ok, the request goes into `doFilter`, be uncrypt, `httpRequest.getDispatcher.forward` and call a second time `doFilter` which finally call `chain.doFilter`.

   Now in spring-boot 2.1.7 requestDispatcher's forward didn't reach a second time `doFilter`... Never found a doc on it.
2. Basic calls like `/api/users` (which means a `findAll`) worked on 1.5.6 but fail with NPE in 2.1.7 cause of sorting. I can't call a `findAll` like `/api/users` or `/api/users/7/books` I always get an error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.Querydsl.applySorting(Querydsl.java:128)

Did someone get explanation for that ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Both `Sort` and `Pageable` now expose dedicated null-objects via `Sort.unsorted()` and `Pageable.unpaged()` to express the absence of sorting or pagination information in particular.

You should already see an IDE warning if you enable the annotation based verification of null values. That said, I just rechecked the Javadoc and referencedocs and think we can do better here. I've filed the following tickets:

- [DATACMNS-1568](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1568) (fixed) - General documentation updates about nullability in the repository reference docs.
- [DATACMNS-1569](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1569) (fixed) - Nullability constraints in Querydsl APIs.
- [DATAJPA-1594](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1594) (fixed) - Tighten nullability constraints in Spring Data JPAs Querydsl integration.

Comment: As I understand it, it is now imperative to indicate the parameters page and sort?
It's not indicate in spring-boot2 changes.

Comment: My IDE "Eclipse" doesn't make warnings, it's not implemented code but injected by dependance and I call by postman not by code line.

Comment: Could you tell me if you will jsut improve documentation? In this case what we are suppose to do to put default sort and page?

Comment: That's mentioned in my answer: `Pageable.unpaged()` and `Sort.unsorted()`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. This is a configuration? Can you give me the link of doc to disable this check cause we still want to keep possibility to don't give sortable or pageable arguments

Comment: Assuming you have a method `findByUsername(String username, Sort sort)`, instead of calling it with `findByUsername("username", null)` to not apply any sorting, you now have to `findByUsername("username", Sort.unsorted())`. The same applies to `Pageable`.